# How to set Region of Interest in OpenCV - JAVA

Tags: java, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I have an image of a business card on which I have preformed perspective transform in order to extract only the card from the image. Now, I want o feed this image to the tesseract-ocr engine. Before that, I want to extract the region of interest that have some text and feed that instead of the whole image. How can I extract just the text from the card.

Here is an example of the image:[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that is going to do this for you. I did it by first finding the contours of the text available on the image and then using those contours on the actual image.

```
     Mat img_grayROI =  Highgui.imread(perspective__transform_file, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

      Imgproc.GaussianBlur(img_grayROI, img_grayROI, new Size(15,15),50.00);Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 15, 4);

      Imgproc.threshold(img_grayROI, img_grayROI, -1, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV+Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);

      Imgproc.dilate(img_grayROI, img_grayROI, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(2, 2)));

      Mat heirarchy= new Mat();
      Point shift=new Point(150,0);

      List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();    

        Imgproc.findContours(img_grayROI, contours, heirarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        double[] cont_area =new double[contours.size()]; 

      for(int i=0; i< contours.size();i++){
             if (Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)) > 50 ){
                 Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));
                 cont_area[i]=Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i));

                 if (rect.height > 25){
                     Core.rectangle(result, new Point(rect.x,rect.y), new Point(rect.x+rect.width,rect.y+rect.height),new Scalar(0,0,255));


                     System.out.println(rect.x +"-"+ rect.y +"-"+ rect.height+"-"+rect.width);
                     Highgui.imwrite(ROI_file,result);
                 }
             }
        }
```

perspective_transform is the source image on which I need to find the ROI.

Hope it helps.